# How to reverse grid layout to be from right to left in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I start doing some project to improve my skill, but I face an annoying issue, my simple project is fetching data from API and render it to the DOM, but the data is in Arabic and its start from right to left, but the grid layout starts from left so the word it's not in the correct order here some images of my project:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy and Paste your relevant code and add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir="rtl"` should do it:

```
<div id="Chapter" className="grid grid-cols-3" dir="rtl">
 ...
</div>
```

See it [working](https://play.tailwindcss.com/5A46aOajLn).

---

Side note: don't post code as image. It might look prettier, but it's not useful: it can't be copy/pasted, so you're less likely to receive an answer.